# Swift2 - convert the reduce() and map() method on the sequence

Tags: swift2

I am not unable to convert the below line of code in swift 2 syntax

```
private func calculateMaxLabelWidth(labels: [UILabel]) -> CGFloat {        
  return reduce(map(labels, calculateLabelWidth), 0, max
}
```

showing error

> 'reduce' is unavailable: call the 'reduce()' method on the sequence

and

> 'map' is unavailable: call the 'map()' method on the sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved here is the latest code

```
      private func calculateMaxLabelWidth(labels: [UILabel]) -> CGFloat {


         //return reduce(map(labels, calculateLabelWidth), 0, max)
        return labels.map(calculateLabelWidth).reduce(0, combine: max)

       }
```